# Setting the value of one vector (array) to that of another through reference

Tags: c, arrays, vector

Essentially I'm learning C code and at the moment for an assignment, I have to create a 3-dimensional space in the universe with any amount of little planets in this space, interacting through gravity.

At this point, I'm trying to set vector A (bodies[i].position), using the vector P ({1,2,3}) as seen below. Although when the code runs, it only sets the first value of the vector A to the first value of P - the rest remain as 0.

the call for VectorSet is in the main function (along with the array p), I've just put it in this format for ease.

```
   typedef struct {
       double vector[VECTOR_DIM];
   } Vector;

   typedef struct {
       double mass;
       Vector position;
       Vector velocity;
       Vector accel;
       float colour[3];
   } Object;

   p[VECTOR_DIM] = {1,2,3};
   VectorSet(&bodies[1].position, p);

   void VectorSet(Vector *a, double vec[]) {
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < VECTOR_DIM; i++) {
           *(double *)(a + 8 * i) = *(double *)(vec + 8 * i);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I do not understand but you set every 8th double with the value of every 8th.

Comment: C  does not have a vector type. Nor does it support references. A pointer is not a reference. And don't use casts if you **really** know you need them and what they actually do!

Comment: I've added additional information, if you could explain how I can fix this, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 8 from the pointer arithmetics and leave only `i`

Comment: When i do this the enumeration of Vector A is 0, 1.87334e-306, 1.62544e+266